Angular go back to page, viewChild is undefined
I have such a sceneario; component A goes to B and when I go back to A , the @viewChild element is undefined. I tried to access it in ngAfterViewInit, ngAfterContentInit but it's always undefined. This is the last I tried:
@ContentChild('item', { static: false }) item: ItemComponent;

 ngAfterContentInit() {
 if (this.item) {
          this.item.resetFilters();
}

EDIT
I also use data that was in the component so I need to know that now I come from back and it's not new navigation :
 if (event.restoredState))
      this.setSavedData()


Can you please share your code in stackblitz

Can you specify whether you actually use ViewChild or ContentChild? A minimal reproducible example would aso help a lot, ideally in an online code editor such as Stackblitz

I am using @viewChild

Back button, causes SPA applications to not work well, because the state is lost at the previous screen, you can trigger a reload of the component using the below code.
You can place this code at the root of your application like app.component.ts.
Below code does not refresh screen but reloads the component.
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private router: Router) {}

@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
onBackButton(event) {
  this.router.navigateByUrl(`${window.location.pathname}`, {
    skipLocationChange: true,
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
  });
}

You can also refresh the page on back button press.
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
onBackButton(event) {
  location.reload()
}

EDIT
I also use data that was in the component so I need to know that now I come from back and it's not new navigation :
 if (event.restoredState))
      this.setSavedData()


Thanks! problem is that now I don't know how to detect that I came from back,  if (event.restoredState) isn't suitable now

@Juniorfullstackdev window:popstate is fired when back button is pressed, then refresh the page?

I need to access the viewchild inside the component so whatever helps is good, however i subscribe to the events in order to save data, and till now i could use event.restoredState and now it's not restored state anymore

@Juniorfullstackdev reload the page or reload the component, then view child will be accessible, reload page is preferred.

but then how will i know that the page has been accessed from back action?

@Juniorfullstackdev no problem, thank you!

You can use ngAfterViewInit and setTimeout to delay it until after the view has fully rendered.
ngAfterViewInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.item) {
      this.item.resetFilters();
    }
  });
}

